# Warning of Google Play Developer policy violation: Action Required

Tags: warnings, privacy, policy, suspend

```
Hello Google Play Developer,

Our records show that your app, XXXX, with package name com.XXXX.XXXXXXXXXX, currently violates our User Data policy regarding Personal and Sensitive Information.

    Policy issue: Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information. Your app requests sensitive permissions (e.g. camera, microphone, accounts, contacts, or phone) or user data, but does not include a valid privacy policy.

    Action required: Include a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's Store Listing page and within your app. You can find more information in our help center.

    Alternatively, you may opt-out of this requirement by removing any requests for sensitive permissions or user data.

    If you have additional apps in your catalog, please make sure they are compliant with our Prominent Disclosure requirements.

    Please resolve this issue by March 15, 2017, or administrative action will be taken to limit the visibility of your app, up to and including removal from the Play Store. Thanks for helping us provide a clear and transparent experience for Google Play users.

    Regards,

    The Google Play Team
```

I have many apps on Google play and i can't update apk of all one by one. 
How to fix this issue?
How to generate Privacy content for following permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Google has been sending out warnings to developers regarding permission issue and privacy policy requirements, more so in the past few months.

You can read one of my colleague's response on Stackoverflow that's similar to yours here:

[privacy policy Permission (S) :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095522/privacy-policy-permission-s/42098173#42098173)

I'll try to adapt it to your situation nonetheless:

Since Google already helped you identify exactly what information they need to see in your privacy policy, you will need to tell your users what information you're collecting in a way that they will understand:

```
"android.permission.INTERNET"
"android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" 
"android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
"android.permission.VIBRATE" 
"android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" 
"android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
"android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" 
"com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"
```

If you need to read more about these permissions and how the group works, [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html).

What Google is saying, essentially, is that you need to describe the above data collection, outline its purpose and disclose it using a privacy policy.

If you want to generate a privacy policy and learn more about how to add it to your app's Store Listing page, you can find more information here: 
[iubenda - Privacy Policy for Android](http://Google%20has%20been%20sending%20out%20warnings%20to%20developers%20regarding%20permission%20issue%20and%20privacy%20policy%20requirements,%20more%20so%20in%20the%20past%20few%20months.%20%20%20You%20can%20read%20one%20of%20my%20colleague's%20response%20on%20Stackoverflow%20that's%20similar%20to%20yours%20here:%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095522/privacy-policy-permission-s/42098173#42098173%20%20I'll%20try%20to%20adapt%20it%20to%20your%20situation%20nonetheless:%20%20Since%20Google%20already%20helped%20you%20identify%20exactly%20what%20information%20they%20need%20to%20see%20in%20your%20privacy%20policy,%20you%20will%20need%20to%20tell%20your%20users%20what%20information%20you're%20collecting%20in%20a%20way%20that%20they%20will%20understand:%20%20%22android.permission.INTERNET%22%20%22android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE%22%20%22android.permission.WAKE_LOCK%22%20%22android.permission.VIBRATE%22%20%22android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED%22%20%22android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS%22%20%22android.permission.READ_CONTACTS%22%20%20%22com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE%22%20%20If%20you%20need%20to%20read%20more%20about%20these%20permissions%20and%20how%20the%20group%20works,%20here.%20(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html)%20%20What%20Google%20is%20saying,%20essentially,%20is%20that%20you%20need%20to%20describe%20the%20above%20data%20collection,%20outline%20its%20purpose%20and%20disclose%20it%20using%20a%20privacy%20policy.%20%20%20If%20you%20want%20to%20generate%20a%20privacy%20policy%20and%20learn%20more%20about%20how%20to%20add%20it%20to%20your%20app's%20Store%20Listing%20page,%20you%20can%20find%20more%20information%20here:%20http://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-for-android-app/)

Comment: Thanks sir to reply. Please tell me it is enough to add link in store listing only or also necessary to add in application? Again thanks for your reply.

Comment: I just posted a comment regarding this situation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195565/should-i-put-privacy-policy-copy-inside-the-app-itself-or-just-on-the-google-pla/42299949#42299949

You will need to have it on both the Store listing and within the app, based on what Google is asking.

Answer (score 0):

probably you could use a text editor which allows text replacement over  a large number of files at once. then you could replace e.g.

```
<manifest>
```

by

```
<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"     />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"    />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Text editors which support text replacement across large numbers of files at once are e.g. Notepad++ or UltraEdit.