# should i put privacy policy copy inside the app itself or just on the google play store listing ?

Tags: android, google-play, privacy-policy

Do I have to put a copy of Privacy Policy inside the app itself, or should i only put the url to it inside google play without even mentioning it inside my app.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about terms of service of a 3rd party site

Comment: @GabeSechan I still do not understand that why do you want to close this question?

Comment: @Mighty This is a 4 year old question, so its really moot.  But he asked if he had to put it in the app.  That's a question about Google's Play Store policies and if that's a requirement.  Questions like that are off topic here-  any question relating to the policies of what's allowed or required for an app store are.  (Asking how to use the app store to upload an app or configure it is on topic).  So asking where to put a privacy policy or how to link it is valid.  Asking if it also needs to be in the app is not.

Comment: @Mighty The reason for this is that policies change frequently, frequently aren't actually fully known and would need to be explained by the company that runs it, and often require legal advice to understand properly.  The first makes for bad questions for SO, the second makes it impossible to answer, and the third makes it off topic for this site.  So such questions should be closed.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you so much for explanation. I will keep these points in mind while posting questions in future.

Comment: I understand your point, but posting the question here and getting the answer has really helped me out, plus over the 4 years the question has been browsed over 2k so people are really looking for the same answer as I did, and there are genuinely good answers in this thread,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Both** as much as possible.

A public URL would most likely be required for that Privacy Policy field by Google Play Store if your app requests sensitive permissions.

If you don't add the URL and your app needs sensitive permissions, you'll receive a [violation warning email from Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100397/warning-of-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required/42206428#42206428). Your app may be unlisted if you don't fix the violation.

Keep in mind that your business **"must conspicuously link to a Privacy Policy"**.

That's a requirement from CalOPPA in the US, but most privacy regulations around the world have a similar requirement: PIPEDA in Canada, Privacy Act in Australia etc.

You have multiple options how to link to your Privacy Policy from within your app: About or Settings screen, Sign-up or Login screens, separate item in the menu etc.

[image: Links to Privacy Policy from Android apps via TermsFeed]

Comment: thanks for your clear answer @TermsFeed, its more than what i asked for i appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the privacy policy is associated with the company that is publishing the app rather than the app.  After all, that is the entity that people are trusting to implement the policy.  So I think it is enough to have it on a company website and refer to this in Google Play.  A key thing is that people should be able to search the web for the company name, or app and find the privacy policy.  While not specifically about Android apps, the following [link](https://www.oaic.gov.au/agencies-and-organisations/guides/guide-to-developing-an-app-privacy-policy)  gives some guidance on this

Note that there are particular circumstances where user's need to be made aware of your approach to their data at the time they would be entering it.  See [Google's website](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/personal-sensitive/)

> If your app collects and transmits personal or sensitive user data unrelated to functionality described prominently in the app’s listing on Google Play or in the app interface, then prior to the collection and transmission, it must prominently highlight how the user data will be used and have the user provide affirmative consent for such use.

Comment: So is yes or what ?? do i need to put a privacy policy inside the app or just in store listing ?

Comment: @Ayoub as it stands, I don't know anything about your app so I can't answer definitively.  Can you add some details in your question about what kind of user information may be collected and sent back to you/your company?

Comment: let say sensitive informations, I am confused whether to put privacy policy inside my app or not ?

Comment: It doesn't hurt to put it in your app, but if the information is sensitive and something users may not expect from the app description then you _must_ put it in the app, preferably display a link when you ask the user to type the data in.

Answer (score 0):

You **NEED** your privacy policy on the Play Store page **PLUS** within the app

Since February 2017 Google enforces [a strict privacy policy requirement on apps requesting sensitive permissions and user data policies](http://www.iubenda.com/blog/warning-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required-policy-issue/).

Please check the following provided by [Google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#privacy) to determine if **either** needs to have a policy or not:

- **For apps that request access to sensitive permissions or data (as defined in the** **[user data policies](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/user-data/)**: You must link to a privacy policy on your app's store listing page and within your app. Make sure your privacy policy is available on an active URL, applies to your app, and specifically covers user privacy.
- **For apps in the Designed for Families program**: You must link to a privacy policy on your app's store listing page and within your app, regardless of your app's access to sensitive permissions or data. Make sure your privacy policy is available on an active URL, applies to your app, and specifically covers user privacy.
- **For other apps**: You're not required to post a privacy policy.

Once you've identified what your app needs, your privacy policy will need the following:

The privacy policy must, together with any in-app disclosures, comprehensively disclose how your app collects, uses and shares user data, including the types of parties with whom it's shared. Outline which sensitive permissions/user data you process and for what purpose:

```
Say you will access their microphone
Say what purpose that serves
And other user data you process (name, email, address, etc)
```

If you need more information you can go to [iubenda - Privacy Policy for Android](http://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-for-android-app/)

Comment: I assume, it is optional.