# Privacy policy issue on play store

Tags: android, app-store, chat

I created my chat application and now i want to upload it on play store. But it puts up this error

```
Your app has an APK with version code 1 that requests the following permission(s): android.permission.CAMERA,android.permission.READ_CONTACTS. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.
```

Is their any way to solve the problem for free i mean without creating my website which lists all privacy policies
Can i use google drive or something else where policies are stored in text file

Comment: I used free domain provider for my privacy policy just so I can successfully upload my app in Play Store. I just created a simple html stating privacy policy etc.

Comment: Which free domain provider did you used

Comment: It's https://www.biz.nf/

Comment: Is it safe and free

Comment: Read more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095522/privacy-policy-permission-s

Comment: Here is another https://www.iubenda.com/blog/warning-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required-policy-issue/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app should have a privacy policy, if your app is accessing sensitive information or in short if your app is showing any request for permission at runtime you should have a privacy policy. You can create a simple html file with your privacy policies and host it in some free providers. Google don't care where it is hosted. You can search google for free web hosting and select one. That is all