# GET_ACCOUNTS permission error with APK upload to Google Play Store

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, apk

I have built a project with Ionic & I cannot upload my APK to the Google Play store. I get the following error:

Your APK is using permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)

I can see this permission in my AndroidManifest.xml file as shown below. I am using Firebase with their database API, AngularFire2. Do I need to create a Privacy Policy for this? Is this easy to do?:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="0.0.2" package="io.ionic.habit" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.emailcomposer.Provider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/emailcomposer_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService" />
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>`

Comment: I ended up creating a privacy policy from the following:

https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add privacy policy url to your application in playstore and it will solve the problem
you can generate privacy policy with below urls

> https://gist.github.com/alphamu/c42f6c3fce530ca5e804e672fed70d78

> https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

GET_ACCOUNTS was moved into the CONTACTS permission group in Android 6.0(>6.0).

Since you are using targetSdkVersion 25(Android 7),try adding READ_CONTACTS (and WRITE_CONTACTS) uses permission in AndroidManifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Or try [privacy policy Permission (S) :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095522/privacy-policy-permission-s)