# How to fix ..Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have developed an android application which can open email client(Gmail, Icloud etc..) while uploading the apk file in play-console I am getting the below-mentioned error 
`android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.` and I am really stuck here for a very long time.

Any guidance will be of great help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [privacy policy Permission (S) :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095522/privacy-policy-permission-s)

Comment: Might be i tired with the possible solution in comments and it worked. thanks @B001 :)

Comment: Note: Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), if an app shares the signature of the authenticator that manages an account, it does not need "GET_ACCOUNTS" permission to read information about that account. On Android 5.1 and lower, all apps need "GET_ACCOUNTS" permission to read information about any account.